Existence of polynomials related to a certain type of Taylor series
I am stuck with the following problem:

Let $d \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that there exists a polynomial $P(x)=a_dx^d+a_{d-1}x^{d-1}+...+a_0$ of degree $d$ such that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^dx^k$$
is the Taylor series at $x_0=0$ of
$$\frac{P(x)}{(1-x)^{d+1}} = \frac{a_dx^d+a_{d-1}x^{d-1}+...+a_0}{(1-x)^{d+1}}$$

The hint is given to calculate the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{d+1}}$ at $x_0=0$ and then proceed by induction.
This is what I have come up with so far: Let $d \in \mathbb{N}$, $P(x)=a_dx^d+a_{d-1}x^{d-1}+...+a_0$ and $g(x)= \frac{1}{(1-x)^{d+1}}$. Then $g^{(j)}(x) = \frac{(k+j-1)!}{(k-1)!} \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+j}}$ for $k\ge1, \,\forall j\in \mathbb{N}$ or equivalently $g^{(k-j)}(x) = \frac{(d+k-j)!}{d!} \frac{1}{(1-x)^{d+1+k-j}}\quad$for the $k-j$-th derivative. Now define $f(x):= \frac{P(x)}{g(x)}$, computing the $k$-th derivative at $x=0$ gives
$$f^{(k)}(0)= \sum_{j=0}^k = \binom{k}{j} \ j!\cdot a_j \cdot \frac{(d+k-j)!}{d!} \quad \text{for} \ 0\le k\le d,$$
$$f^{(k)}(0)= \sum_{j=0}^d = \binom{k}{j} \ j!\cdot a_j \cdot \frac{(d+k-j)!}{d!} \quad \text{for} \ k\gt d$$
My idea is to show by induction on $d$ that for all $d \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$ \\ k^d = \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ and then take the limit $\lim_{k \to \infty}$. This means I have to show that
$$k^d = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{d+k-j}{k-j}a_j \quad \text{for} \quad 0\le k\le d, \quad (1)$$
$$k^d = \sum_{j=0}^d \binom{d+k-j}{k-j}a_j \quad \text{for} \quad k\gt d \quad (2).$$
I know that for any $d$ the equation in $(1)$ uniquely determines all the coefficients of the polynomial of degree $d$. But i do not understand how to show that the so obtained coefficients solve $(2)$ for all $k$ greater than $d$.
If I am on the right path then can someone give me a hint on how to proceed and use the induction hypothesis? Or can someone suggest another induction hypothesis?
